# Play Midi/Audio files using PC speaker

Tags: audio, speakers

I have managed to create a digital keyboard using a pi, a pc speaker and this tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nyYOYrsPZa4
But since I'm not much of a pianist or an audio engineer I would like to play some kind of file on my pc speaker.
I have tried to disassemble a midi file and extract one voice and then just feed the notes and timings into the shellscript using a file, but that just doesn't seam to work, the notes are all random somehow even though the timing seams correct. So I think the notes are just sort of incompatible.
So heres my question: how do I create a musicfile that includes the notes playable by a pc speaker (or a piano), that includes the notes and timings that a music sheet would have, or more simple, how do I get a music sheet as a txt file?

Comment: A note is a note. A middle C lasting 200ms is a middle C lasting 200ms. If you have a known good midi file and you're getting random notes played, either you're interpreting the file wrongly or you're passing the notes to your thing wrongly. To answer your question, a MIDI file IS a solution to the problem - an example of a file which stores notes (playable by a PC speaker - although this part is irrelevant). You could create a new one, but what would be the point? It might also not work for the same reason.

Comment: Thanks, its good to know that it should work in theory. I don't know much about music, so its a bit hard to tell. I'll look over my code again, thanks